# <__main__.Animal object at 0x037D07B0> Error python 3

Tags: python, class

trying to do an assignment and am stuck on a memory address.
I have thought up 2 different ways of overcoming this, but both are not quite there...

Heres an example of my attempt (i dont think im allowed to post my code online)

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self,string1,integer1):
        self.string1 = string1
        self.integer1 = integer1

    def __repr__(self):
        print('-------------------------')
        print('#' + self.integer1 + '' + '-' + ' ' + string1)
        print('-------------------------')

I want it to print like this:

    -------------------
    # 5 - hello
    -------------------
```

If i use a **repr** method i get a 'cant convert 'int' object to str implicity' error.
If i use a **str** method instead i get a memory error
If i try to use return, i cant because it requires multiple lines to be returned.

I need to keep the types of each object variable the same and i need to only have that output with no memory error afterwards...

Hopefully this problem isnt to hard (or to easy :P) im pretty new to OOP in python 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you think about the `str.format` method?

Comment: You missed a `self` inside `__repr__` print statement

Comment: Note that `__repr__` and `__str__` must *return a string*, not `print` things...

Comment: traceback is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\School\Uni\First Year\COSC121\Wing IDE 101\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "F:\School\Uni\First Year\COSC121\Wing IDE 101\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 8, in __repr__
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: i have tried the format method, i have managed to get it working for just strings but i cant get it going for multiple types ie, ints and strings

Comment: @AlexWhite and the [mcve] for that is `'#' + 1`. Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed. Search for the error message and you'll find dozens of duplicates.

Comment: Woops sorry :/, trust me iv been looking all over for the answer i can't seem to work it out. None the less, note taken ill make the code simpler

Comment: You already have your answer, but two more things: Firstly, your code looks as if it was better of using `namedtuple`, check out the according documentation. Secondly, you can edit your question to make it clearer, your traceback as a comment is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+` for string concatenation , you cannot add a string to an integer. Example -

```
>>> 5 + 'asd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Python is a strongly typed language, it will not automatically convert integer to string during string concatenation.

You should instead use some string formatting method, like `str.format()` .

Also, another thing to note would be that you would need to return the value from `__repr__()` instead of print it. And then if you want it printed in console you should call `print(a)` (or `print a` in Python 2.x). Example -

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self,string1,integer1):
        self.string1 = string1
        self.integer1 = integer1
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("-------------------------\n"
                "#{} - {}\n"
                "-------------------------").format(self.integer1,self.string1)
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> class example(object):
...     def __init__(self,string1,integer1):
...         self.string1 = string1
...         self.integer1 = integer1
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return ("-------------------------\n"
...                 "#{} - {}\n"
...                 "-------------------------").format(self.integer1,self.string1)
...
>>> a = example('hello',5)
>>> print(a)
-------------------------
#5 - hello
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the problems in your attempt.

```
print('#' + self.integer1 + '' + '-' + ' ' + string1)
```

See, you miss a self here.

Secondly, this will raise a `concatenation` error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

That's because, `self.integer1` is an `int`, cast it to `str`. Or even better, use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

Thirdly, you shouldn't print it at all.

> **repr** should return a printable representation of the object

You are printing inside `__repr__` which shouldn't be used like that. You rather change it like that:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self,string1,integer1):
        self.string1 = string1
        self.integer1 = integer1

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#' + str(self.integer1) + '' + '-' + ' ' + self.string1


print('-------------------------')
print example("hello",5)
print('-------------------------')
```

Comment: The `print()` function will not raise an error, the error occurs before `print()` is called. Also, your code will not run on current Python versions.